# Open Source VB6 applications

Tags: open-source, vb6, sample

I'm not 100% percent sure that this is a programming related question, but here it goes.

I'm looking for sample VB6 applications, but I need fully-functional applications, with database access and with the source code.

I Googled a lot before asking the question here, but I couldn't find anything like what I'm looking for.

Any links would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tons of samples on [vb6.us](http://www.vb6.us/) or [vbcode](http://www.vbcode.com/)

Comment: There are plenty of VB6 examples on CodeProject -http://www.codeproject.com/Forums/1646/Visual-Basic.aspx

Answer (score 0):

VBMigration.com have an interesting [list of open source VB6 projects](http://www.vbmigration.com/Documentation/codesamples.aspx).